# if(conf&lt;50): ; SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

i am buliding face recognition code with python and opencv. this line giving the error in ; .when i replace ; with > or any other operator it works but lt become unknown this shows error like this.... NameError: name 'lt' is not defined.

**This is my whole code in detector.py**

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec= cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
rec.read("recognizer\\trainingData.yml")
id=0
fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
fontColor = (255, 255, 255)

#font = cv2.InitFont(cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
while True:
    ret, img =cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    #print(rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]))
        id, conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if(conf&lt >= 50):
            if(id==1):
                id="Osama"
            elif(id==2):
                id="Psycho"
        else:
            id = conf
        cv2.putText(img,str(id), (x,y+h), fontFace, fontScale, fontColor)
    cv2.imshow('Face',img) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: show your code . provide more information . detail error log . after all we're developers not god

Comment: Show us more code than that please so we can help you.

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: before this line `if(conf&lt >= 50):`the variable  `lt` is never mentioned....so it is not defined as the error says, maybe it is a typo?

Comment: Interesting the fact that you have `if(conf&lt;50)` in your title and `if(conf&lt >= 50)` in the code you show... maybe it really is `if(conf&lt;50)` and then `&lt;` should be replace by `<` which is what `&lt;` is the code for (as `lt` stands for *lower than*).

Comment: i copied code from https://thecodacus.com/face-recognition-loading-recognizer/#.WmgoeaiWbDc. Above code is almost same .when i make this change  if(conf&lt >= 50):  it gives this error NameError: name 'lt' is not defined .Using this code if(conf&lt;50) it shows syntax error on ;

Comment: Just have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you replace `;` with an operator, when you should in fact replace the whole code (`&lt;` which stands for *lower than*) with `<`.

So `if(conf&lt;50)` would give you `if(conf<50)`.

See [special chars in HTML](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php).

Comment: @Osama, in your link there's the line `if cv2.waitKey(10) &amp; 0xFF==ord('q'):` where the `&amp;` seems to have been improperly transcoded as well, it needs to be `if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):`